# Gitlab - SSH KEY doubdt

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

although I know that this is my first question within Stack overflow so I will try to be as consist as possible, I continue.

Within where I work, I am in charge of implementing and training the development team to use tools related to git, within the same we use gitlab, a tool in which until now I have learned to move but as every human being I had to adapt, what that now has become a stone in the shoe has been everything related to ssh keys to be able to access the repositories of the company, my doubt is regarding that, I know that every time you create a gitlab repository you recommended create a key ssh, I already create one, so, every time I use the first repository that I create, I do not have a problem when doing commits, push, pull, or all the other related commands, but when I want to use or clone another repository for console, I miss the error
"git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. "

So my question is, every time I create a new repository, clone, or any other referral, I will have to be creating a new ssh key ?? .. can not create one for everything? ...
These have expiration date ?? ... or that .... I ask for help from the most experienced to see if you can clarify this doubt .. thank you very much in advance I read them !! Thank you !!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome on SO.

**No**, **you don't need to create an SSH key for each project** / repository.

Once you've created an SSH key and added it to your Gitlab account, you'll just have to add user permission to manage new repositories.

[image: Gitlab users on projects]

Here is something that can be useful to you : [Gitlab permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html)

Answer (score 0):

> These have expiration date ??

Actually, with GitLab 12.10 (April 2020), the SSH keys *can* have an expiration date:

> ### [Optional SSH key expiration date](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/04/22/gitlab-12-10-released/#optional-ssh-key-expiration-date)
>
> Compliance-minded organizations need a way to control SSH credential access to their GitLab environment.
>
> SSH keys are normally configured without expiration dates.
>   This is problematic for organizations with access management and/or credential management policies, which require an expiration date on all access credentials.
>
> With this release, GitLab supports expiration dates for SSH keys that users can set within the GitLab UI.

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/12_10/optional-ssh-key-expiration.png]

See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/36243).